# Get the image of an element that gets drawn in the three.js while rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

Well the way I think three.js handles the render is that it turns each element into an image and then draws it on a context.
where can I get more information on that.
and if I am right, is there a way to get that image, and manipulate it?

any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js internally has a description of what the scene looks like in 3D space, including all the vertices and materials among other things. The rendering process takes that 3D representation and projects it into a 2D space. Three.js has several renderers, including [WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js) (the most common), [CanvasRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js), and [CSS3DRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js). They all use different methods to draw that 2D projection:

- WebGLRenderer uses JavaScript APIs that map to [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) graphics commands. As much as possible, the client's GPU takes parts of the 3D representation and more or less performs the 2D projection itself. As each geometry is rendered, it is *painted* onto a *buffer*. The complete buffer is a *frame*, which is the complete 2D projection of the 3D space that shows up in your `<canvas>`.
- CanvasRenderer uses JavaScript APIs for 2D drawing. It does the 2D projection internally (which is slower) but otherwise works similarly to the WebGLRenderer at a high level.
- CSS3DRenderer uses DOM elements and CSS3D transforms to represent the 3D scene. This roughly means that the browser takes normal 2D DOM elements and transforms them into 3D space to match the Three.js 3D internal representation, then projects them back onto the page in 2D.

(All this is highly simplified.)

It's important to understand that the *frame* rendered WebGL and Canvas representations is the resulting picture that you see on your screen, but it's not an `<img>`. Typically, your browser will render 60 frames per second. You can extract a frame by [dumping the `<canvas>` into an image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/). Typically you'll want to stop the animation loop in order to do this as otherwise you might not be capturing the frame you want. Capturing frames this way is slow and given that your browser is rendering so many frames per second there are not easy ways to capture every frame.

Additionally, Chrome has built-in [canvas inspection tools](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/05/debugging-with-chromes-canvas-inspection/) which allow you to take a closer look at each frame the browser paints.

You can't easily intercept the buffer as Three.js is rendering the frame, but you can draw directly onto the canvas as you normally would. `renderer.context` is the graphics context that Three.js draws onto, where `renderer` is the Renderer instance you create when setting up a Three.js scene. (A graphics context is basically a helper to assemble the buffer that makes up the frame.)

Comment: thanks for your useful information, but it would be really useful if we could get each element rendered separately, or get the visible pixels of an element...

Comment: I suppose you could do that by rendering each object in your 3D space onto separate canvases. You can also toggle on/off rendering certain objects.